# Jasper Report Server -How to add a Calender Input Contral

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using the latest jasper report server and when i add the calender option to filter the dates in the report.
I added a Single value input control and selected datatype from the repository(/datatypes/date) .But still it doesn't give me a calender option it only display input control to enter the date manually.

How can i do this ..? Can anyone provide me an example to overcome this issue... I also want to know how to combine the calender option to my report too..

Comment: I found how to add the calender option. We can define a new DataType as Date and it will add a calender option.But i still have no idea how to map this into my JRXML report.. Can anyone give me an example please..

Comment: you must have a parameter with then same "ID" as you input control

Comment: Yes i got it...Input control names should be same as the parameter names...